# Translations working but not translating

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site.
I set as default language Portuguese and added another language as English.

I was able to translate everything but then I don't know what happened. All the blocks are working fine but when i try to translate a Basic Page this is what happens:

Example:
My basic page is in Portuguese (as default). I click "translate" and choose "English". I change the title and body of the Basic Page and save.

Then, when i switch to portuguese, **everything is in English** even the Portuguese Version!
And when I go change the portuguese version to portuguese translations, **everything changes to portuguese**.

**The title is the only thing that says Portuguese and English respectively.**

Any clues to what's going on? Can anyone help me?

Thank you!